# Is there a way to automatically cut everything away outside of an object?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm pretty new to Blender and I'm stuck right now.

I created a complex 3D Structure with another program and imported the STL file. Now I need to "cut" this object into a cylindrical form. The object needs to be placed in a pipe after 3D printing. The boolean modifier does'nt seem to be the right option. I have tried to invert the difference operation by using a hollow cylindrical mesh but it didn't work. Does anyone have an idea how this is possible?

Comment: so all the parts of your original object that will pass through the cylinder are supposed to be cut off?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So the imported structure is now in a cubic shape. And it needs to be cut into a cylindrical shape to fit into the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand (?) I would do it that way (I tried with intersect with no success)

[image]

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was looking for. But I have successfully confused myself now. Did you use the intersect oder difference operation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nevermind, it works with the difference operation. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Boolean/Difference   ;)